# Compute the range of column height

Tags: java

The key of the below code is to find the tallest and shortest block in a column. I created a method that gets the tallest block. I need help with getting the range of the highest and lowest block and returning that range.  I get that I'm getting the max height but  I feel very lost with what I need to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Helper Code
--get the tallest height of a block

```
public int getColumnHeight(Board board, int col){

    int highestPiece = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < Board.HEIGHT; row++){

        if (board.isBlockAt(col, row)){
            highestPiece = row + 1;
        }
    }
    return highestPiece;
}
```

-- get the range of column heights (need help with this portion)

```
public int getColumnHeightRange(Board board){

     int columnHeightRange = 0;

     for (int col = 0; col < Board.WIDTH; col++){
        int columnHeight = getColumnHeight(board, col);
        if (columnHeight > colHeightRange){
            colHeightRange = columnHeight;
        }
    }
    return colHeightRange;
}
```

Comment: ```getColumnHeightRange``` method only gets the Max height, you could make a new method that will get the Min height. Combine the result of both method to get the range

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like colHeightMAX and colHeightMin are always set to the integer min / max and never get reassigned to anything. This means that any item that is greater than Integer.MIN_VALUE will activate the first if statement and colHeightRange will be set equal to Integer.Min because the variable hasn't changed anywhere. I'm not sure if this is the behavior you want

Comment: @Patrick, Thanks. I realized that after I ran the code that it wasn't behaving as expected. Back to the drawing board.